# how do i fix the symfony cache generated files

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I have just started working with symfony2 and I have a huge road block that I can't seem to figure it out. I have create a new class called AppKernel to register my Bundles,etc.

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles=[
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new mdBundle\mdBundle(),
];
    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(function ($container) {
        $container->loadFromExtension('framework', array(
            'secret' => 'some secret here',
            'router' => array(
                'resource' => '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml'
            ),
            'templating' => array('engines' => array('php'))
        ));
    });
}

}
```

My front controller looks like this:

```
include_once(__DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php');

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require '../../app/vendor/autoload.php';

Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

The error msg that i get is the following:Type error: *Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolverInterface, boolean given, called in /var/www/html/app/classes/cache/dev/classesDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 367*
I am just not sure how this file gets created with the wrong value(the value is false"boolean") for argument 4.

Here is my composer.json file.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "symfony/console":"v3.0.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.5.7",
        "zendframework/zend-db": "2.2.5",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "v3.0.0",
        "symfony/config": "v3.0.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "v2.3.5",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer" : "v5.2.9",
        "smarty/smarty" : "3.1.12",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy": "*",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.6",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "*",
        "moredirect/service": "dev-master",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "2.*",
        "gongo/merciful-polluter": "^0.0.3",
        "solarium/solarium": "^3.5",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "v3.0.0",
        "symfony/form": "3.0.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.6.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.10.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "3.0.0",
        "symfony/finder": "3.0.0",
        "symfony/filesystem": "3.0.0",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "3.0.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "v3.0.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "3.0.0"
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: `php bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: I tried that and it will only remove the files once it is generated again the error happens again.

Comment: I'm not sure why your AppKernel.php looks completely different from that one included in the standard edition.

Comment: BTW I don't understand why would you create AppKernel.php yourself while you have just started using Symfony?! Could you  please tell us reasons behind? Are you creating your own framework from SF components

Comment: The reason I am creating a appkernel is becsuse I omly need to use specific packaged from symfony. I am migrating our app that uses our home grown framework. I have tried also using the standard appkernel and still got the same error.

Comment: Which versions of the FrameworkBundle and of the HttpKernel component do you use?

Comment: If you only need a specific package from symfony then you should just be able to get it via composer, see the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html) for how to use their components

Comment: Again, which version of Symfony are you using? Starting with 2.8, you have the MicroKernel, that wil greatly simplify having a "reduced" kernel.

Comment: As far as the version i believe it is synfony2. I didn't start from a blank project  generated by symfony. I started pluging in the packages i needed in order to make our my app to work. I have added my composer.json file  in the main edit section. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out i was missing the following line in the composer.json file:

```
"symfony/http-kernel":"3.0.0"
```

After i added it is working fine. thank you for all the comments.